# C#. Вопрос по Перечислению (enum)

Tags: c#, enum

C#. Можно ли Константе Перечисления (enum), присвоить Значение из обычной Переменной?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что значит "Константа Перечисления"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, значения констант менять нельзя. Будь то enum или объявленный const, они не изменяются ни при каких обстоятельствах, в этом их суть.

Comment: Скажем так, констант вообще не существует во время выполнения :)

Comment: Да, всё так. И, соответственно, их можно изменить если всунуться в нужную ячейку памяти. Но я не считаю что такие подробности уместны в данном контексте :)

Comment: константы в коде захардкодены, их нельзя поменять просто поменяв ячейку в памяти.

Comment: О боги, вы правы ! Проверила, Enum действительно остается вхардкоженным, что нельзя сказать о константах объявленных через const, о них уже в IL коде ничего неизвестно

Comment: это потому что константы существуют только в коде, во время запущенной программы их нет, они как бы захардкожены в код прямо получаются. Это кстати обычный вопрос на собесах по C# - чем ридонли поля отличаются от констант.